# Tomcat AD Authentication - Allow all AD users

Tags: java, tomcat, active-directory, ldap

How can I allow all users in the AD to login to my application (enforce that they login)? Not just defined by group.

This is my web.xml.

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>MyApplication</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>

</security-constraint>

<security-role>
  <role-name>some-ad-role</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
  <role-name>another-ad-role</role-name>
</security-role>

<!-- Basic Authentication using a JNDIRealm -->
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Login</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

I still want to use AD groups for authorization within my application using request.isUserInRole() but initially everyone can login to the application in order for me to have their username for checking purposes.

Comment: Possible dublicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720343/ldap-authentication-via-web-xml-in-tomcat

Comment: @Cratylus those examples talk include restricting login to only defined roles using <auth-constraint> in the security constraint... my problem is slightly different - I need to allow all users no matter what group they are in, as long as they are in AD.

Comment: We put up [Tomcat And LDAP](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/Tomcat%20And%20LDAP) on the wiki that should help.

Answer (score 0):

So I couldn't find any documentation but I seem to have solved this issue by using a wildcard for the role-name.

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>MyApplication</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>

    <auth-constraint> 
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>

</security-constraint>

<security-role>
  <role-name>some-ad-role</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
  <role-name>another-ad-role</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role> 
    <role-name>*</role-name>
</security-role>
```